# Find incorrect objects from list to save network requests

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, binary-search

I have 100 objects, some of them are correct and the other could be incorrect.
I would like to find corrects **only** objects from the 100.

I have a function `bool isCorrect(List<object> objs)` (`O(1)`) that get x objects and return false if at least one object is incorrect - I can't change that function.

Every `isCorrect` call make a network request. So you would like to save requests.

What Iv tried?
1. Run each object `isCorrect`- `O(n)`
 2. Run binary search - if 100 is return incorrect split to 50 50 and etc... - `O(log2(N))`.

The worst case is `O(log2(N))` + `O(N)`
Can I find any other algorithm better than that?

Comment: What is the complexity of "isCorrect"?

Comment: isCorrect is complexity of O(1)

Comment: I don't think you can find a faster algorithm than the one you describe. What is the context of this problem?

Comment: Why? isn't it similar to "The Two Egg Problem"?

Comment: I think you are talking about Dynamic Programming with Memorization?

Comment: How are you going to separate **some** objects with binary search in log(n)?

Comment: @ManjeetThakur it's an option. I don't find an algorithm that can solve my problem.

Comment: @MBo binary search complexity is log(N), ill split the list and try again

Comment: @John Daves It is nice ;) But helps to discover **one** incorrect object rather than many (more thoroughly - any incorrect object)

Comment: @MBo you right. 
I also update my question complexity of worst case .

Comment: What is exact problem formulation? Perhaps some details might help.

Comment: If all objects are incorrect, you need to test each one individually. There is no way to determine that in less than N requests.

Comment: If you have some idea of the probability of an object being incorrect, then if that probability is _p_ and _p_ is small(ish), you could chop the list into _1/(2*p)_ (or _1/(4*p)_) parts before proceeding to the binary chop phase.  Also, you could stop the binary chop and fall back to the linear scan when the sub list reaches some small number of objects (4, 8, ?).  So, you can reduce the **O**_(log2(n))_ component a little.  How likely is the worst case  (do you really care) ?  If the incorrect objects are not randomly distributed, then you may have a different problem.

Comment: Do you really have a method that can tell in O(1) time whether a list contains any incorrect objects, or is this a hypothetical problem? If it's not hypothetical, then however you're able to test a property of all objects in a list in O(1) time I don't know, but there is probably a way to adapt the way it works which is simpler than calling it in some kind of binary search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is [output sensitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Output-sensitive_algorithm). Let's suppose your output is the list of sequences of objects that are correct, then the minimum complexity you can reach is Omega(length of this list).

Comment: My minimum complexity I can reach if all object are correct is O(1) because I call just once isCorrect() and it's return TRUE

Comment: Yes, you reach O(1) complexity only in this case. In all cases (including this trivial case), you can reach O(size of output)

Answer (score 0):

O(n) is provably optimal in the worst case.

Consider the family of inputs where all but one object is incorrect. The output must be a list containing just that object, but the only way to find it is by testing the objects one at a time; any test on more than one object will always return `true` because at least one of them is incorrect.

That means you need to do n tests on singleton lists in the worst case, which takes O(n) time. You do need to do all n tests because if you skip any of them, you could miss the one object that's correct.